# Having lots of trouble using cin robustly in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I can't seem to come up with a chunk of code that traps the user until it gets a positive int and prompts the user appropriately if the user accidentally types a character or random garbage like "-1-3-4-39-32xfi3/". I just need a neat failproof cin loop structure and can't figure it out. Thanks.

I'm just wondering what other people do regarding console input to make draw ideas from that..how you get around bad input.

Comment: So what "chunk of code" have you come up with that isn't working the way you expect? This reads like a homework question that's poorly disguised. If you were "playing around with something", you should have at least one attempt at solving the problem that you can include in your post. Please [edit] to do so. Otherwise, from [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." I don't thing "can't figure it out" and "playing around with something" counts.

Comment: From C++-faq, [How can I get std::cin to skip invalid input characters?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html)

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        unsigned int n;

        if (!(iss >> n >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF)
        {
            std::cout << "Bad input ('" << line << "'), ignoring.\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Success! We read: " << n << "\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    std::cout << "Premature end of input!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

In other words, continue reading input from the user until you are able to parse the input as the kind of data you want. I chose line-based processing, which is often the most natural, but any notion of "record" that you can skip if it isn't right will do. Note that it's possible the program never succeeds, namely if the user refuses to provide *any* good input.

Comment: That seems a little excessive, don't you think?

Comment: @remyabel: Nope. It's precisely right.

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/4dIvVq).

Comment: @remyabel robust console input is hard in C and C++!

Answer (score 0):

I typically read an entire line with `std::getline`, then attempt to convert it to an integer with `strtol`. If the result is less than 0, they typed a leading `-`. `strtol` returns a pointer to the first character of input that couldn't be converted as an integer, so if it points to anything but `\0`, you know the user typed in something that couldn't be converted.

I really should switch to using `std::stoi` instead of `strtol` though. It supports pretty much the same capabilities, but its input is a `std::string` instead of a C-style string like `strtol` uses. I only continue to use `strtol` out of long habit, not because it's really a better solution.

Depending on what you have available, and how you want to respond to bad input, another possibility to consider would be boost `lexical_cast`. This throws an exception if it can't convert the entire input to the target type, so if you want an exception it may be more convenient (but if you don't want exceptions, it'll probably just cause you extra work).